How to deserialize nested Pydantic models from JSON where nested models are held in a list on a computed field
I have a Pydantic model representing a bank account holding transactions, which themselves are models that are nested on the account model. The transactions are held in a list on a hidden field and accessed through a computed field that applies some checks in the setter method.
Simplified Models:
class Account(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    owner: Customer
    _transactions: List[Transaction] = list()

    @fields.computed_field()
    @property
    def transactions(self) -> List[Transaction]:
        return self._transactions

    @transactions.setter
    def transactions(self, list_: List[Transaction]) -> None:
        # DO SOME CHECKS
        self._transactions = sorted_list

class Transaction(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    date: datetime.date = Field(frozen=False)
    amount: PositiveFloat = Field(frozen=False)

class Customer(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    name: str = Field(frozen=False)

Serialization
I can successfully serialize an account to JSON, including the transactions:
x = my_account.model_dump_json()
x

Formatted output:
'{
    "id":"1eeed00b-3bd7-48fa-ab6a-6979618ef723",
    "owner":{      
        "id":"0cad242dad03-492b-9c6b-86f0b75f9c00",
        "name":"Bob"
    },
    "transactions":[
    {"id":"42738f1d-e998-4add-94b8-713afe25b525","date":"2012-01-01","amount":1.0}
  ]
}'

De-serialization (unexpected behavior)
However, when I try to reconstruct the model from the JSON string, the transactions field is left empty. No issue with the owner field, which holds the nested Customer model:
Account.model_validate_json(x)

Formatted output:
Account(
    id=UUID('1eeed00b-3bd7-48fa-ab6a-6979618ef723'), 
    owner=Customer(
        id=UUID('0cad242d-ad03-492b-9c6b-86f0b75f9c00'), 
        name='Bob'
    ), 
    transactions=[]
)

Is there a way to make the serialization process for a computed field reversible?

Credit to Yurii Motov for getting me most of the way to the answer. I was able to make this work using a model validator in 'wrap' mode, which allows access to the pre-validated dictionary (from the JSON) and access to the Account model instance.
Full code example:
class Account(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    owner: Customer
    _transactions: List[Transaction] = list()

    @fields.computed_field()
    @property
    def transactions(self) -> List[Transaction]:
        return self._transactions

    @transactions.setter
    def transactions(self, list_: List[Transaction]) -> None:
        # DO SOME CHECKS
        self._transactions = sorted_list

    @model_validator(mode="wrap")
    def validate_model(self, handler: ModelWrapValidatorHandler['Account']) -> 'Account':
        _transactions = []
        # self is the dictionary form of the JSON when model_validate_json       
        # is called
        if isinstance(self, dict):
            for t in self.get("transactions", []):
                _transactions.append(Transaction.model_validate(t))

        # The handler is called on self to do the model construction
        validated_self = handler(self)
        validated_self.transactions = _transactions

        return validated_self

class Transaction(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    date: datetime.date = Field(frozen=False)
    amount: PositiveFloat = Field(frozen=False)

class Customer(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    name: str = Field(frozen=False)



Account.model_validate_json(
    '{
        "id":"1eeed00b-3bd7-48fa-ab6a-6979618ef723",
        "owner":{      
            "id":"0cad242dad03-492b-9c6b-86f0b75f9c00",
            "name":"Bob"
        },
            "transactions":[
                {
                    "id":"42738f1d-e998-4add-94b8-713afe25b525",
                    "date":"2012-01-01",
                    "amount":1.0
                }
            ]
    }'
)

```

Formatted output:
```python
Account(
    id=UUID('1eeed00b-3bd7-48fa-ab6a-6979618ef723'), 
    owner=Customer(
        id=UUID('0cad242d-ad03-492b-9c6b-86f0b75f9c00'), 
        name='Bob'
    ), 
    transactions=[
        Transaction(
            id=UUID('42738f1d-e998-4add-94b8-713afe25b525'),
            date=datetime.date(2012, 2, 20),
            amount=1.0
        )
    ]
)
```


upd: it's incorrect answer, you can't actually use self in model validator with mode="before".
Thanks @Richard Riley for noticing!
You should use model validator with mode="wrap" as it's shown in @Richard Riley's answer.
You can do it using model validator:
    @model_validator(mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def validate_model(self, data: Any):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            self.transactions = data.get("transactions", [])
        return data

Full code example:
import datetime
from typing import Any, List
from uuid import UUID, uuid4

from pydantic import (BaseModel, Field, PositiveFloat, computed_field,
                      model_validator)


class Transaction(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    date: datetime.date = Field(frozen=False)
    amount: PositiveFloat = Field(frozen=False)

class Customer(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    name: str = Field(frozen=False)

class Account(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    owner: Customer
    _transactions: List[Transaction] = list()

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def validate_model(self, data: Any):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            self.transactions = data.get("transactions", [])
        return data



    @computed_field()
    @property
    def transactions(self) -> List[Transaction]:
        return self._transactions

    @transactions.setter
    def transactions(self, list_: List[Transaction]) -> None:
        # DO SOME CHECKS
        self._transactions = sorted(list_, key=lambda a, b: a.amount>b.amount)



a = Account.model_validate({
  "id": uuid4().hex,
    "owner":{      
        "id":uuid4().hex,
        "name":"Bob"
    },
    "transactions":[
    {"id":uuid4().hex,"date":"2012-01-01","amount":1.0}
  ]
})


print(a.model_dump())

Output:
{'id': UUID('0f7f32a1-b3b9-40e8-a35d-e662e5e4032e'), 'owner': {'id': UUID('bca37eaa-086a-4adf-b51c-e05feb812e9b'), 'name': 'Bob'}, 'transactions': [{'id': '87042f4e738a4b24888e6c126260edc3', 'date': '2012-01-01', 'amount': 1.0}]}


Thank you. Model validator was the answer. The class method in your example references 'self' so doesn't work. I have posted how I got it to work using a model validator in 'wrap' mode so it can access both the raw dict from the JSON and the instance of Account that we need to attach the list of Transactions to.

I really missed the thing with self. Thanks for noticing!
